# excel formula to filter range based on criteria

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, formula

I have a strange problem I've been trying to find a good solution to for the past few hours.  I have a table in excel similar to the following:

```
     |A     B     C     D     E     F
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
1    |2011  1     0    -5     4     2
2    |2011  2     1     1.2   2     3
3    |2011  3     1     2     4    -4
4    |2011  0     1    -3     3    -2
5    |2012  5     1     0     0     1
6    |2012  0     1     0.25  0     0
```

the data falls into different categories based on columns A-C, with columns D-F being dollar amounts.

What I'm trying to figure out is, is there a way to return the max absolute value of columns D-F for a subset of these rows using the values in columns A-C as filter values?  Now, I know how to return the max absolute value of a range: `=max(abs(START:END))`, but what I don't know how to do is filter out some of the rows from the range based on their column A-C values.

Perhaps a specific example of what I'm looking for:

How would I get the range D-F where:

- A=2011
- B<>0
- C=1

For the above set of conditions and data, the answer I'd like to have returned is 4, from E3.

I am not opposed to adding helper columns within reason, but there are many more sets of filter conditions, which was the undoing of a few other solutions I cobbled together; 16-32 helper columns would not be accepted by the group I'm trying to develop this for.

Comment: Does your excel version support maxifs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) version supports the newer [MAXIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883), use that with the ABS function and [MINIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599).

```
=max(maxifs(d:f, a:a, 2011, b:b, "<>", c:c, 1), abs(minifs(d:f, a:a, 2011, b:b, "<>", c:c, 1)))
```

If not then AGGREGATE will provide the conditions.

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, ABS(D1:F6)/((A1:A6=2011)*(B1:B6<>0)*(C1:C6=1)), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: sadly my version of excel does not seem to support the MAXIFS function.  fortunately, the aggregate seems to be just the ticket.  thanks!